# IE javascript - document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onclick, onmouseover

Hi Im trying to hide/show a series of panels. It works in FF but not IE. Ive added this to the bottom of the page to hide all of them and then show the first panel

```
function clearem(){
document.getElementById("panel01").style="display:none";
document.getElementById("panel02").style="display:none";
document.getElementById("panel03").style="display:none";
document.getElementById("panel04").style="display:none";
document.getElementById("panel05").style="display:none";
document.getElementById("panel06").style="display:none";
document.getElementById("panel07").style="display:none";
document.getElementById("panel08").style="display:none";
document.getElementById("panel09").style="display:none";
document.getElementById("panel10").style="display:none";
document.getElementById("panel11").style="display:none";
}
function showem(mrfoo){
clearem();
document.getElementById("panel"+mrfoo).style="display:block!important"; return false
}
clearem();
showem("01");
```

theyre triggered manually by:

```
<a href="#rail" onMouseOver="showem('09')" onClick="showem('09')">Railway</a></li>
```

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

UPDATE - ive moved the display out of the quotes. it doesnt work offline but does online!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning a string to the `style` property.

Assign your values though `style.display` instead.

Answer (score 2):

you should be doing:

```
document.getElementById("panel11").style.display="none";
```